# how to get column of latest row mysql

Tags: mysql, groupwise-maximum

The query below is fine with me except the content in column **message_content** is of the first row in table **al_messages**. How can I get the content of the latest row?

```
SELECT a.CONVERSATION_ID, 
       a.CREATOR_ID, 
       c.SCREEN_NAME       AS creator_screen_name, 
       c.FIRST_NAME        AS creator_first_name, 
       c.LAST_NAME         AS creator_last_name, 
       Count(d.MESSAGE_ID) AS messages_count, 
       MESSAGE_CONTENT 
FROM   AL_CONVERSATIONS a 
       INNER JOIN AL_SUBJECTS b 
               ON a.SUBJECT_ID = b.SUBJECT_ID 
       INNER JOIN AL_MEMBERS c 
               ON a.CREATOR_ID = c.MEMBER_ID 
       INNER JOIN AL_MESSAGES d 
               ON a.CONVERSATION_ID = d.CONVERSATION_ID 
WHERE  a.SUBJECT_ID = 301 
       AND b.CREATOR_ID = 17 
GROUP  BY a.CONVERSATION_ID
```

The query result:

[image]

Comment: This is probably the most frequently asked question in this category (MySQL). In light of this, it amazes me how often the solutions suggested are wrong, but you should be able to sort the wheat from the chaff.

Comment: Can you show me the correct way?